# Unable to persist object : detached entity passed to persist

Tags: jpa, jsf-2

I am using JSF - EJB3 - Hibernate JPA2.0 in my application. In one of the screens when I try to persist a new entry, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: info.novatec.timemgmt.entities.Customer
```

Following are chunks of my code that may be helpful,

View:

```
<h:form>
  <h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel value="Customer:" for="customer" />
    <h:selectOneMenu id="customer" value="#{projectController.selected.customer}" title="Customer" >
      <f:selectItems value="#{customerController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:outputLabel value="Name:" for="name" />
    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{projectController.selected.name}" title="Name" />
    <p:calendar id="endDate" value="#{projectController.selected.endDate}" showOn="button" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" size="10"/>
  </h:panelGrid>
```

Managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CustomerController implements Serializable {

    // ...

    public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableSelectOne() {
            return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(ejbFacade.findAll(), true);
    }

    // ...
}
```

`JSFUtil` helper class:

```
public class JsfUtil{

    public static SelectItem[] getSelectItems(List<?> entities, boolean selectOne) {
        int size = selectOne ? entities.size() + 1 : entities.size();
        SelectItem[] items = new SelectItem[size];
        int i = 0;
        if (selectOne) {
            items[0] = new SelectItem("", "---");
            i++;
        }
        for (Object x : entities) {
            items[i++] = new SelectItem(x, x.toString());
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Could you please point as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: I am sorry, but The code that I inserted for JSF is not displayed, but is available when I try to edit.

Comment: I've already edited it. In the future, pay attention to the preview area below the message editor before submitting the message and read the message formatting rules in the editor's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `Converter` for the `Customer` class (which you omitted from the question, but it's surely there in your real code). You seem to be manually constructing a `new Customer()` with an ID instead of obtaining the `Customer` instance from entity manager by its ID. Fix the converter accordingly.